# Angular2: ng-switch not working as expected

Tags: angular

i followed the syntax for ng-switch from official site:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

and this is how i am using ng-switch :

```
<div ng-switch="accessLevel">
<div class="customer" ng-switch-when="ENABLED">This is customer data</div>
<div class="customer-blurr"  ng-switch-when="DISABLED"> This is disabled Customer Data</div>
<div class="customer-blurr" ng-switch-default> <demo-error [componentName]="componentname"></demo-error></div>
</div>
```

> accessLevel is "DISABLED" but still i am getting "This is customer
>   data".

i print out the accessLevel just to verify and its "DIABLED"

here is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
})
export class CustomerComponent extends SuperChildComponent{
  public allowed: boolean = false;
  public  accessLevel:AccessLevel =null;
  public componentname:string;

  constructor(private authenticationService : AuthorizationService) {
    super();
    this.componentname=this.constructor.name;
     this.accessLevel=this.authenticationService.isUserLoggedIn()?this.authenticationService.componentAccessLevel(this.constructor.name):null;
     console.log(this.constructor.name +' has '+this.accessLevel);
  }
```

I have **also tried**

> ng-switch-when="accessLevel==ENABLED" and
>   ng-switch-when="accessLevel===ENABLED"

but still its executing only the first switch condition(this is what i think), since accessLevel is "Disabled"

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like Angularjs 1.x syntax

In Angular2 it's `*ngSwitchCase`, `*ngSwitchDefault`, ...

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitchDefault-directive.html

Comment: thanks a lot:) i overlooked the angular version in doc